# Can I make an array out of a range of countif functions?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

A truncated version of my data is in the form shown in the screenshot below: three columns of 5 unique names. The names appear in any order and in any position but never repeat in a single row.

My goal is to create an array that contains the number of times Adam appears in each row. I can fill down the formula`=countif(A2:C2,$I$2)` in a new column, or if I write the array manually for each row, it looks like:

```
={countif(A2:C2,$I$2);countif(A3:C3,$I$2);countif(A4:C4,$I$2);countif(A5:C5,$I$2);countif(A6:C6,$I$2)}
```

Where cell I2 contains "Adam". Of course, this is not feasible for large data sets.

I know that arrays are effectively cells turned into ranges, but my main issue is that the cell I'm trying to transform already references a range, and I don't know how to tell the software to apply the countif down each row (i.e. I intuitively would like to do something like countif((A2:C2):(A99:C99),"Adam") but understand that's not how spreadsheets work).

My goal is ultimately to perform some operations on the corresponding array but I think I'm comfortable enough with that once I can get the array formula I'm looking for.

[image: Data sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(IF(A2:C="Adam", 1, 0), {1;1;1})))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, this does exactly what I was looking for! If you can, could you walk me through what the formula is doing? I don't quite understand the IF statement and what matrices are being multiplied (and why). It looks like you found a creative solution however and I appreciate it.

Comment: sure. IF A2:C equals Adam it will replace it with 1. if it does not equal Adam then it will be 0. this is then passed into MMULT which sums each column (represented as {1;1;1}) of those previously computed zeros and ones. the outer IF is just cosmetic to get rid of zeros till end of the column.